# Emboss image with height difference

Tags: modeling

is there a way to emboss an image to a shape with height difference, for example with a 2D circle the center is the highest position and the outer is the lowest height?

*need to be applied not only on simple shape

Answer (score 2):

You can use a height map on bump node via image texture. You can download height maps online or create your own. White areas will emboss more and it will reduce according to black and white.

[image: Height map I created from photoshop]

[image: Node Setup]

[image: Final Preview]

Comment: as far as im aware its  only affecting the texture(?) is there a way to make it affect the mesh itself?

Comment: You may have to Convert Material Displacement to a Mesh which will be little bit complex. As you mentioned that "*need to be applied not only on simple shape" in my point of view Convert Material Displacement to a Mesh will not suitable on complex models.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, really appreciate it

Comment: @alvaro You could bake the texture (without displacement, just plugged straight into the material output) and then use the image as the texture for a _Displace_ modifier.

Answer (score 1):

To nondestructively displace a mesh, you use the *Displace* modifier.  The modifier takes a texture to modify the mesh with, which can be any of a number of built-in procedural textures; or you can use an image texture.

The mesh you wish to displace must have enough geometry to be distorted, of course.  Here's an example with a plane:

- Create a plane
- In edit mode subdivide edges to give it a lot of geometry.  Here I used 10 cuts.

[image: Last Operator adjust panel showing 10 cuts]
[image: modified plane]

- Add a displace modifier

[image: Displace modifier]

- Left click the *New* button to create a texture for the displace modifier.  You can change the name if you'd like.
- Go to the texture properties and make sure that *Displace* and your texture's names are selected:

[image: Displace texture settings]

I used *example* as my texture name.

- If you want to use an image, select it using the *Open* button in settings. For this example I selected a built-in *Clouds*

[image: Selecting the clouds procedural displacement texture]

If you are still in edit mode, the change won't show up, but when you return to object mode, your mesh will be displaced.

[image: displaced mesh]